# Location of Azure AD session tokens

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on

I am reading on the Single Sign on using Azure AD.I wanted to know where the SSO Session tokens are being stored. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes

The reason being is that I have a web application which uses SSO authentication on Azure AD. It never prompts for credentials even after clearing the local storage and cookies. So wanted to know where these session tokens are being stored.

Comment: Are you using SAML for single sign-on?

Comment: No, it's OpenAuth2 with Open Connect

Answer (score 1):

Sessions in Azure AD are usually stored in cookies that are stored in your browser for the Azure AD domain.

You can clear the single sign-on session by redirecting the user to log out at Azure AD's signout endpoint.
See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-protocols-oidc#send-a-sign-out-request

Comment: thanks for the answer. That is the way of doing it programatically. But I wanted to know where to search and clear these cookies manually in the browser.

Comment: Here is for Chrome: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95647?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en. Here is for Firefox: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/clear-cookies-and-site-data-firefox#w_clear-cookies-for-any-website. Search for `login.microsoftonline.com`.